# Unable to transform json array in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am new to mule and I am unable to transform this nested array to my required format. I searched various links but couldn't find much help relevant to my requirement.
I am attaching the snippet which I have tried till now and I am unable to figure out how to proceed further.

**Code**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var myvar={
    "name" : ["Shawn","James","Paul"],
    "sd" : ["2020-12-23","2020-12-24","2020-12-24"],
    "ed" : ["2020-12-25","2020-12-28","2020-12-27"]
}
---
myvar.name zip myvar.sd zip myvar.ed
```

**Required Output**

```
[
    {       
        'name': "shawn",
        'sd': "2020-12-23",
        'ed': "2020-12-25"      
    },
    {       
        'name': "james",
        'sd': "2020-12-24",
        'ed': "2020-12-28"      
    },
    {       
        'name': "Paul",
        'sd': "2020-12-24",
        'ed': "2020-12-27"      
    }   
]
```

**Actual Output**

```
[
  [
    [
      "Shawn",
      "2020-12-23"
    ],
    "2020-12-25"
  ],
  [
    [
      "James",
      "2020-12-24"
    ],
    "2020-12-28"
  ],
  [
    [
      "Paul",
      "2020-12-24"
    ],
    "2020-12-27"
  ]
]
```

**Any sort of guidance or hint or any relevant links would be very helpful to me.**

Comment: do you know any online compiler for code?

Comment: @DaniilLoban what kind of compiler are you expecting?

Comment: Karthik, for run you code

Comment: You can run your own instance of the playground using the docker image located at https://hub.docker.com/r/machaval/dw-playground

Comment: Instructions to setup the same - https://medium.com/@ramsunka/dataweave-transformation-editor-for-desktop-ef02d460f470

Comment: @SalimKhan Is it just an online tester for testing dataweave scripts or it does something else too?

Comment: Its a playground to create , execute and test your scripts.

Comment: Thank you @SalimKhan . I will follow that for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.. Many ways to solve this though!!

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var myvar={
    "a": ["Shawn", "James", "Paul"],
    "b": ["2020-12-23", "2020-12-24", "2020-12-24"],
    "c": ["2020-12-25", "2020-12-28", "2020-12-27"]
}
---
1 to 3 map 
{
    name: drop(myvar.a,($-1))[0],
    sd: drop(myvar.b,($-1))[0],
    ed: drop(myvar.c,($-1))[0]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SalimKhan .That worked well...Can you just explain shortly how this works? I am kind of new to this

Comment: Sure..  I am trying to create a for loop of sorts using 1 to 3 or i could do 1 to sizeOf(myvar.a) (if the size of the three arrays is always going to be the same).  After that its about building the object that is needed. Drop is core arrays function (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-drop) that drops the first n elements specified in the function defintion - drop (array,n) and returns an array with the rest of the elements. So in each of the iterations i keep picking the first element from the remainder array.

Comment: In first iteration (when $ =1 , since its starting from 1)  it would have dropped none, and thus [0]th element would actually give the first required set of "Shawn" ,"2020-12-23","2020-12-25" . Next when $ = 2 it drops Shawn and keeps James and Paul and [0]th element there would give me James and the remainder of the fields for sd and ed. Similarly when $ is 3 , it would have dropped the first two elements and what remains is details for Paul which i can pick using the [0]th element, since the drop function always returns an array. HTH.

Comment: Thanks @SalimKhan...That was very much helpful.. But if size of array varies someday, in that case what should i do? Like now if the each array has 5 elements in that case what should I do?

Comment: 1 to sizeOf(myvar.a)

Comment: ya figured it out...thank you...a personal question like how could I get good grip in dataweave? any tips? @SalimKhan

Comment: Practice,read  and maybe keep visiting stackoverflow more often with DW related questions and solutions :)